# How to calculate average age from highly segmented population data in SQLlite?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have been given the problem of:

Write a query that shows the average age of a person in California in 2018.

The formula for the average age is shown below.

=∑(+0.5)∗/∑

I am supposed to get the result of:

```
average
0   38.487045
```

A select * from population gives the base data in this format:

```
fips    county  year    age pop_female pop_male  pop_total
6001    ALAMEDA 1970    0   8533        8671    17204     
6001    ALAMEDA 1970    1   8151        8252    16403     
6001    ALAMEDA 1970    2   7753        8015    15768     
6001    ALAMEDA 1970    3   8018        8412    16430     
6001    ALAMEDA 1970    4   8551        8648    17199
```

.....and so on from ages 1-100 and years 1970-2018

I tried using this:

```
select (sum(age + 0.5) * (pop_total) / sum(pop_total)) as 
              average from population group by year having year = 2018
```

But that gave me the result of:

```
average
0.05875349176742352
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the first multiplication *inside* the `sum()`.  Most databases would generate an error for this, but some accept your syntax:

```
select (sum( (age + 0.5) * pop_total) /
        sum(pop_total)
       ) as average 
from population
where year = 2018
```